# Cannot send aps to iOS using aws-sdk-js

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

I am trying to use aws-sdk-js to send push notification to iOS and Android device. It can send the notification message, but it is not the one I wanted. If i put `badge` and `sound` in the `aps` dictionary, the app should have a badge and play a sound. But it did not.

Xcode console output:

```
[aps: {
alert = "Test Message";
}]
```

javascript code:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: '<key>', secretAccessKey: '<secrect>'});
AWS.config.update({region: 'ap-southeast-2'});
var sns = new AWS.SNS();

var payload = {
    default: 'Test Message',
    APNS: {
        aps: {
            alert: 'Test Message on iPhone',
            badge: 1,
            sound: "default"
        },
    }
};

payload.APNS = JSON.stringify(payload.APNS);
payload = JSON.stringify(payload);


var params = {
    MessageStructure: 'json',
    Message: payload,
    Subject: 'Test push',
    TargetArn: '<arn of the endpoint>'
};


sns.publish(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
    else console.log(data);
});
```

code in  `application:didfinishlaunch`,

```
    let acceptAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    acceptAction.identifier = "ACCEPT_IDENTIFIER"
    acceptAction.title = NSLocalizedString("Accept", comment: "Accept")
    acceptAction.activationMode = .Foreground
    acceptAction.destructive = false
    acceptAction.authenticationRequired = false

    let deleteAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    deleteAction.identifier = "DELETE_IDENTIFIER"
    deleteAction.title = NSLocalizedString("Delete", comment: "Delete")
    deleteAction.activationMode = .Foreground
    deleteAction.destructive = true
    deleteAction.authenticationRequired = false

    let ignoreAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    ignoreAction.identifier = "IGNORE_IDENTIFIER"
    ignoreAction.title = NSLocalizedString("Ignore", comment: "Ignore")
    deleteAction.activationMode = .Foreground
    deleteAction.destructive = false
    deleteAction.authenticationRequired = false

    let messageCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
    messageCategory.identifier = "MESSAGE_CATEGORY"
    messageCategory.setActions([acceptAction, deleteAction], forContext: .Minimal)
    messageCategory.setActions([acceptAction, deleteAction, ignoreAction], forContext: .Default)

    let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Badge, .Sound, .Alert], categories: (NSSet(array: [messageCategory])) as? Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>)

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
```

and implement the protocol:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {


    print(userInfo)
}


func application(application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, forRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], withResponseInfo responseInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], completionHandler: () -> Void) {

    print(identifier)


    completionHandler()

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a developer profile for apns you should write APNS_SANDBOX instead of APNS

```
var payload = {
    default: 'Test Message',
    APNS_SANDBOX: {
        aps: {
            alert: 'Test Message on iPhone',
            badge: 1,
            sound: "default"
        },
    }
};
```